# Is session.modified = True in flask redundant now?

Tags: python, session, flask

As Flask API documentation says, I need to add

```
session.modified = True
```

after my code in order to propagate session changes to mutable structures like dict/list.

As I understand, session object won't see any changes and won't add modified session data to cookies.

Example#1 from docs:

```
session['objects'].append(42)
# so mark it as modified yourself
session.modified = True
```

Example#2 from google:

```
# Add a logout handler.
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Delete the user's profile and the credentials stored by oauth2.
    del session['profile']
    session.modified = True
    oauth2.storage.delete()
    return redirect(request.referrer or '/')
```

But I tried Flask 1.0.2 and Flask 0.10.1. Everything **also** works without `session.modified = True` between requests. I see changes, cookies are updated.

Is that line redundant now?

Comment: When you say that "it works", are the changes persistent, or is it only working when the same client happens to connect to the same thread/process/instance? For example, If you're only running Flask with the local test server, if you quit and restart Flask and reconnect with the same cookies, is the `42` still appended to `session['objects']`?

Comment: [quote]For example, If you're only running Flask with the local test server, if you quit and restart Flask and reconnect with the same cookies, is the 42 still appended to session['objects']?[/quote]

Yes, 42 is appended. 

If I use persistent sessions, data is available when I close and open browser.
If I do not use persistent sessions, data is available only between requests.
This behavior is expected.

Comment: Do you have other behavior?

Comment: I use this option. But presence or absence of it doesn't effect overall behavior. I see session.modified = True as redundant.

Comment: So, I figured out a problem. Behavior depends on version of python. Using python 2.7 works as documentation says. Using python 3.7 session.modified = True is unnecessary. My question - why?